# calculus antiderivative of $\tan(\cos^2(x))\sin(2x)$

Tags: calculus

Find the antiderivative of $\tan(\cos^2(x))\sin(2x)$.

I have tried but couldn't finish. Let $\tan(\cos^2(x))=u$, then $du=-\frac{\sin(2x)}{cos^2(cos^2(x))}$. Let $\sin(2x)=dv$, then $v=-\cos(2x)/2$.

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\cos^2x=u,-\sin2x\ dx=du$

$$\int\tan(\cos^2x)\sin2x\ dx=-\int\tan u\ du=?$$